# How do I combine these two columns? Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, combinations

I have two columns one is Buyer ID and one is Seller ID. I'm trying to simply find out which combination of both appears the most.

```
def twoCptyFreq(df,col1,col2):
    cols=[col1,col2]
    df['TwoCptys']=df[cols].astype(str).apply('+'.join, axis=1)
    return (df)

newdf=twoCptyFreq(tradedf,'BuyerID','SellerID')
```

I get the results I want however sometimes i get 1234+7651 and 7651+1234, so the same two but i need to aggregate these together. How do I write this into my function to allow for cases wher the buyer and seller may be switched?

Answer (score 3):

You can sorting values - in lambda function by `sorted`:

```
df['TwoCptys']=df[cols].astype(str).apply(lambda x: '+'.join(sorted(x)), axis=1)
```

Or in columns converted to 2d array by [`np.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html):

```
df['TwoCptys']= (pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[cols].values, axis=1))
                   .astype(str).apply('+'.join, axis=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1],'B':[2,3,2],'C':[9,9,9]})

df['combination']=df['A'].astype(str) + '+' + df['B'].astype(str)

df['combination'].value_counts()
out[]:
1+2    2
1+3    1
Name: combination, dtype: int64

#This shows combination of df[A] ==1 and df[B] ==2 has more occurences
```